# Access tinymce 4 from jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, tinymce

Actually I am developing a plugin for tinymce 4 and I need to access tinymce from jquery.
How can I access it.
I have looked at tinymce Jquery version but I don't know how to use it.
Please somebody help me out.

Answer (score 0):

with the jQuery version you send commands like this

```
$('#content').tinymce().execCommand('Bold');
$('#content').tinymce().execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<b>Hello world!!</b>');
```

as you can see in this tinyMCE fiddle:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/eaaaab